# Scala Slick 3.1 simple column<->case class mapper

Tags: scala, enums, slick-3.0

i'm trying to use a simple custom slick column example, [as described in here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/schemas.html). Given this "enum":

```
trait EntityType

object EntityTypeImplicits {
  implicit def fromString(s: String): EntityType = s match {
    case "external" => ExternalEntity()
    case "user" => UserEntity()
    case "packet" => PacketEntity()
    case "share" => ShareEntity()
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Unknown entity type")
  }
  implicit def toString(e: EntityType): String = e match {
    case ExternalEntity() => "external"
    case UserEntity()     => "user"
    case PacketEntity()   => "packet"
    case ShareEntity()    => "share"
  }
}

case class ExternalEntity() extends EntityType
case class UserEntity() extends EntityType
case class PacketEntity() extends EntityType
case class ShareEntity() extends EntityType

case class Entity(identity: String, entityType: EntityType)
```

and this schema config

```
trait Schema extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  implicit val entityTypeMapper =
    MappedColumnType.base[EntityType, String] _
  implicit val tt: TypedType[EntityType]

  class Entities(tag: Tag) extends Table[Entity](tag, "entities") {
    def identity = column[String]("identity", O.PrimaryKey)
    def entityType = column[EntityType]("type")
    def * = (identity, entityType) <>
            (Entity.tupled, Entity.unapply)
  }
}
```

This gives a compile-error:

```
[error] No matching Shape found.
[error] Slick does not know how to map the given types.
[error] Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
[error]   Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
[error]      Source type: (slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[domain.EntityType])
[error]    Unpacked type: (String, domain.EntityType)
[error]      Packed type: Any
[error]     def * = (identity, entityType) <>
[error]                                    ^
```

I don't understand -- i've provided mapping rule, so Slick can actually convert my "enum" to string and back, why does he complain?

p.s. I am *very* new to Slick (and Scala, to be honest).

Answer (score 1):

Following the example in [the docs](http://http:/http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/userdefined.html#using-custom-scalar-types-in-queries), it basically just looks like you didnt set up your mapping object correctly.

```
 implicit val entityTypeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[EntityType, String] (
      EntityTypeImplicits.toString,
      EntityTypeImplicits.fromString)
```

This should do the trick... you basically need to give the two functions capable of performing this conversion (not sure what you are doing in your case by giving underscore?). I also have more explicitly defined type information in the table class but I doubt this matters, just something extra to aid in troubleshooting...

```
def entityType : Rep[EntityType] = column[EntityType]("type")
```

Hope that helps! I find the Slick docs to be a little meh, & Googling can lead you into a rabbit hole of deprecated syntax...